# Solving for mortgage payment amount and its deduction on the total principal?

Tags: mortgage, loans, payment, annuity, financing

This question is stumping me.

> "Jane has taken out a 20-year, $150,000 mortgage with monthly payments (made at the end of each month) at a stated mortgage rate of 6.8% per year compounded semi-annually. If she makes each payment on time, what will be the mortgage principal remaining after 10 years?"

How to approach this question and answer it? I've got a test and need to solve this by hand using a calculator.

It says 'stated mortgage rate': am I supposed to convert that to the effective annual rate?

Comment: In the US, mortgage interest accrues each month. I've never heard of an amortized mortgage compounding semi-annually. Are you sure you read this correctly?

Comment: Yes, this is the question we were given. It's a hypothetical example for a university question in the course. I copied and pasted it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about homework.

Comment: @littleadv But... *is* homework off-topic? See [Meta - Should homework questions be allowed?](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/446/should-homework-questions-be-allowed) This kind of question *would* otherwise fit the site, wouldn't it?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Canadian mortgages compound semi-annually.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea and perhaps the OP could have included `canada` as a tag. Also, as mhoran_psprep's answer points out, Canadian mortgages _do_ compound monthly at a rate that needs to be calculated from the legally stated rate of x% per annum compounded semi-annually.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea - Is there a decent reference to how, exactly this is calculated? Does that process mean the standard PMT/PV/FV/Int/Nper finance calculators don't produce the exact numbers for your mortgages?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that you review the course material, but this is what [I was able to find](http://www.yorku.ca/amarshal/mortgage.htm):

> Unfortunately, mortgages are not as simple. With the exception of
>   variable rate mortgages, all mortgages are compounded semi-annually,
>   by law. Therefore, if you are quoted a rate of 6% on a mortgage, the
>   mortgage will actually have an effective annual rate of 6.09%, based
>   on 3% semi-annually. However, you make your interest payments monthly,
>   so your mortgage lender needs to use a monthly rate based on an annual
>   rate that is less than 6%. Why? Because this rate will get compounded
>   monthly. Therefore, we need to find the rate that compounded monthly,
>   results in an effective annual rate of 6.09%. Mathematically, this
>   would be:
>
> ((1+rM)^12)-1 = 0.0609
>
> rM = (1.0609)^(1/12)
>
> rM = 0.493862…%
>
> Notice, that the annual equivalent of his rate is slightly less than
>   6%, at 5.926% (0.493862 x 12 = 5.926%). In other words, 5.926%
>   compounded monthly is 6.09% annually. By the way, I recommend to my
>   students learning this for my university courses that they use 8
>   decimals in their interest rate to assure that they can be accurate to
>   the penny.

the original 0.0609 is (1.03*1.03 )-1